# Is there a faster way to check BitmapData.getPixel32() using AS3?

Tags: performance, actionscript-3, actionscript, bitmap, bitmapdata

I am using the conventional way to check if a random/single pixel on a transparent bitmap is non-zero, using `bitmapData.getPixel32(x,y)!=0`

But is there a faster way to do this, since this is kinda performance heavy. I think there must be a way to do this, maybe using a byteArray?

How can I do this the best way? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a quite an interesting article on working with pixels with the help of vector and getVector-method.

Mike Chambers did a case study on this with the help of Grant Skinner's performance-tool and was looking into ways to increase performance in AS3. Read all about it here:

http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/2009/10/13/case-study-actionscript-3-performance-optimization/

Answer (score 0):

You could perhaps speed things up a bit by using bitmapData.getColorBoundsRect() and check for non transparent pixels.

You then only need to check the pixels *inside* the bounds rectangle, since you know all pixels outside the rectangle must be transparent.

```
// returns bounds rectangle for all non transparent pixels
bitmapData.getColorBoundsRect(0xFFFFFFFF, 0x000000, false);
```

Comment: Yeah but how do I apply this to the getPixel and make it faster? Because I know exactly which pixel I need to have with X and Y, and with the getColorBoundsRect you just isolate the rectangle which doesn't contain those colors, and what do I have to do then?

Comment: getColorBoundsRect would make most sense when you need to loop through all pixels in the bitmap, so it doesn't sound like it would help you out in this case

Comment: Yeah that is true, sorry I forgot that. But my question is what is the fastest way for a single/random pixel!